# AWS Services Mocking using jest

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, mocking, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock some of the AWS services in my project , I have placed them in the folder **mocks**

ex.

```
 __mocks__
        |__ aws-sdk.ts
```

So in the aws-sdk.ts

```
export const getFn = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation(() => ({ promise: ssmGetParameterMockResponse }))

export class SSM {
  getParameter = getFn
}

aws_sdk.SSM = SSM
module.exports = aws_sdk
```

the ssmGetParameterMockResponse is in another mock data file , which has the value as

```
export const ssmGetParameterMockResponse = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
  Promise.resolve({
    Parameter: {
      Value: JSON.stringify({
        Endpoint: 'http://abcdef.com',
        AppToken: 'AppToken',
        UserToken: 'UserToken',
        Name: 'Bleh',
      }),
    },
  })
)
```

in my ts file

```
const ssm = new AWS.SSM()
const credentials = ssm
  .getParameter({
    Name: String(CRED),
  })
  .promise()
  .then(({ Parameter }) => JSON.parse(Parameter?.Value || '{}'))
const { Endpoint, UserToken, AppToken, Name } = await credentials
```

In my test file when i try this test case , all are working fine , my mock data is coming from my **mocks** folder which uses the data from ssmGetParameterMockResponse , but there are some test cases where i have to overwrite the values provided from ssmGetParameterMockResponse , i mean i have to remove the property 'name' to check whether the code is getting failed and i catch them correctly,

I tried the below in my particular test case , where i wanted to remove the name property

```
    const spyyy = jest.spyOn(mock, 'ssmGetParameterMockResponse')
    spyyy.mockReturnValue(
      Promise.resolve({
        Parameter: {
          Value: JSON.stringify({
            Endpoint: 'http://abcdef.com',
            AppToken: 'AppToken',
            UserToken: 'UserToken',
          }),
        },
      })
    )
```

but no luck still i'm getting the details properly , is there any other way i can overwrite the mocks ???

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to export AWS clients from their own module, it makes for easier mocking

Example below.

// amazonClients.js

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";

export const ssm = new AWS.SSM();
```

// index.js

```
import { ssm } from "./amazonClients" 

export const getCredentials = async () => {
  return ssm.getParameter({ Name: String(CRED)}).promise()
}
```

// index.test.js

```
import {getCredentials} from "./index";
import {ssm} from "./amazonClients";

jest.mock("./amazonClients");


test("should return cred", async() => {
 ssm.mockReturnValue({ promise: () => Promise.resolve(STUB_SECRET) })

 const credentials = await getCredentials()
 
 expect(credentials.Name).toEqual("foo")
 expect(ssm).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is from using `jest.spyOn`. Since you're already working with a mock function, there's no need for that. Instead just give the mock function a new mock return value.

```
ssmGetParameterMockResponse.mockReturnValue(
  Promise.resolve({
    Parameter: {
      Value: JSON.stringify({
        Endpoint: 'http://abcdef.com',
        AppToken: 'AppToken',
        Name: 'Bleh',
      }),
    },
  })
);
```